# Crash on ListView adapter after obfuscating

Tags: android, listview, proguard

After obfuscating my app stops working. I use Gradle. It`s part of my build.gradle.

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        debuggable false
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFile 'other-proguard-rules.pro'
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.releaseSigning
    }
}
```

Here is mt other-proguard-rules.pro

```
-keepattributes *Annotation*

-keep class com.polites.android.** { *; }
-keep interface com.polites.android.** { *; }

-keep class com.handmark.pulltorefresh.library.** { *; }
-keep interface com.handmark.pulltorefresh.library.** { *; }

-keep class android.support.v7.internal.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.v7.internal.** { *; }
-keep class android.support.v7.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.v7.** { *; }

-keep class com.google.** { *;}
-keep interface com.google.** { *;}
-dontwarn com.google.**
```

Trouble with ListView adapter.

```
mTriggerList.clear();
mTriggerList.addAll(triggerList);
notifyDataSetChanged();
```

If I comment "notifyDataSetChanged();" that everything works. But of course the list is not updated.
Without comment - crash.
What could be the reason?

Comment: please post the logcat of your crash